# SqlHierarchyId.Parse failed because the input string '1.1.3' is not a valid string representation of a SqlHierarchyId node

Tags: sql-server

I have created a `VARCHAR` column named 'SequentialOrder' in one of my SQL Server tables. It holds the version number of an application, in the format 'MajorVersion.MinorVersion.RevisionVersion', e.g. '2.5.1'. I want to retrieve the contents of this table and sort them by the AppVersion number in a descending order, so that the latest version is on top.

However, when I do an `ORDER BY SequentialOrder ASC`, the results are sorted by string sorting and not numerical sorting. So 12.1.1 comes below 5.1.1, which is wrong for the purposes of what I want to do. Any ideas on how I can resolve this problem?

```
    SELECT     sectionorder
    FROM         section
    ORDER BY CASE 
       WHEN sectionorder<> '' THEN sectionorder
            ELSE CAST('/' + REPLACE(sectionorder, '.', '/') + '/' AS hierarchyid)
       END
```

-output:
11.9.0
1.1
3.2
1.1.3
2.3.4
1.4.5
1.2.9
[empty string]
[empty string]

I need Exact output like this:
1.1
3.2
1.1.3
1.2.9
1.4.5
2.3.4
11.9.0
[empty string]
[empty string]

Comment: What happens when you run that query not using ColdFusion?

Comment: (Edit) You need to post more details about the SequentialOrder column. However, based strictly on the error message it looks like the conditions are reversed. You probably meant to do the replace and convert to `hierarchyId` when SequentialOrder is NOT empty, ie `WHEN SequentialOrder = '' THEN '/'
       ELSE CAST('/' + REPLACE(SequentialOrder, '.', '/') + '/' AS hierarchyid)`.  FYI - updated question tags. This question is about SQL Server, not CF.

Comment: I don't even understand how this is possible if SequentialOrder is a hierarchyid datatype in the table.

Comment: @PrakashG - Thanks for posting more details.  (Side note, great Shakespeare quote in your profile!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server, the [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) function.

```
SELECT     GCOI, SequentialOrder, SortTitle
FROM         Title
ORDER BY CAST( ISNULL( PARSENAME( SequentialOrder, 3 ), -1 ) AS int) DESC
    , CAST( ISNULL( PARSENAME( SequentialOrder, 2 ), -1 ) AS int) DESC
    , CAST( ISNULL( PARSENAME( SequentialOrder ,1 ), -1 ) AS int) DESC
```

Updated to reflect `null` order by last requirement.
Updated again to reflect descending order.

Comment: But I need a null values should be last. Now null values in first. versions  number are in last.i need a ascending order using order by clause

Comment: Just wrap it with an ISNULL( PARSENAME(SequentialOrder, n ), 99999 )

Comment: 1 11.9.0
2 1.1
3 3.2
4 1.1.3
5 2.3.4
6 1.4.5
7 1.2.9
8 [empty string]
9 [empty string]
10 [empty string]
11 [empty string]
12 [empty string]
13 [empty string]
Top of the versions number needs to be ascending order and null values should be last. this is my output. Can you please help me. sorting is not working.

Comment: @J.T. - Neat idea. However, I think the sort needs to be reversed, ie 3,2,1. To sort the nulls last, add a case first, ie `ORDER BY CASE WHEN SequentialOrder IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CAST( PARSENAME( SequentialOrder, 3 ) AS int), etc....`

Comment: (Edit) @PrakashG - Are the strings *always* in this format, major.minor.rev? Also, can you add that last comment to your question? The lack of formatting in comments makes it hard to distinguish values from line/item numbers.

Comment: (Edit) @PrakashG - If the strings are not *always* in this format: major.minor.rev, then PARSENAME may not do the trick here.  JT - 1,2,3 sorts by rev,minor,major. (*if* all the string has all three parts)

Comment: If they aren't,  then we are basically writing his code for him to come up with the exact string parsing syntax to get it correct in this singular situation.

Comment: (Edit) Yes, obviously they will have to play around with it. Just pointing out the potential issues with this method given that their sample data is different than described (and the ordering 1,2,3) , so they are not chasing their tail.. ;-)

Comment: I need ascending order and null values should be last.

Comment: I updated the query again @PrakashG, Thanks for picking up on that, leigh.

Comment: Thanks for help me.I above mentioned some output. Can i get that exact output like that.

Comment: @PrakashG Just mess around with the query a bit to get it working. All the pieces are there. If you want ascending, then change them all to ASC and the -1 to 999999

Comment: I got ascending order but i'm not get that exact output. thanks for support me. I don't know how resolve it.

Comment: Can any one please give the solution for exact output? i above mentioned exact output.